# calling a public function of an asp.net ajax server control from client side

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax, callback, custom-server-controls, servercontrols

I want to make a ajax server control in ASP.NET and in that application I have a textbox and I want to send text of that textbox to function that is created in ASP.NET ajax server control class and that function return some result based on text.

My Application uses Server controls which are Imported from External DLL added as a reference. This Server Control will make use of AJAX to complete its functionality.

To use My control, I would add the Script Manager and My Control on the .aspx page and it should start working.

Comment: did you get succeed in this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a Script Manager to the page
2. Add a new web service file to the project
3. Add the attribute [ScriptService] to the service class
4. Create a method that accepts and returns a string ie:
5. Add the attribute [ScriptMethod] to the method
6. On the aspx page with the script manager, add a Service reference to the asmx file
7. Call the server side method in javascript qualifying it with the full namespace.

MyPage.aspx:

```
...
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/MyService.asmx" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
...
<script>
    MyNameSpace.MyService.MyMethod('some text', responseHandlerMethod, errorHandlerMethod);
</script>
...
```

MyService.asmx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [ScriptService]
    public class MyServiceClass: System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [ScriptMethod]
        [WebMethod]
        public string MyMethod(string SomeText)
        {
            return "Hi mom! " + SomeText;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My Project consists of a DLL which will be imported into a project and the Server control will be used from That DLL. So I think I cannot depend on an External Web Service. I need to Make a call to my internal public function and pass some data and get some result.