# Call c# method from jquery ( slider )

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to call a c# Method everytime a jquery UI slider event is happening.

This is pretty much the basic code of the jquery ui slider:

```
    $("#slider").slider({
        value: <%= getDayOfWeek() %>,
        min: 0,
        max: 6,
        step: 1,
        slidecreate: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val(day[ui.value]);
            $("#MainContent_tagAuswahl").val(ui.value);
        },
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val(day[ui.value]);
            $("#MainContent_tagAuswahl").val(ui.value);

        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( day[$( "#slider" ).slider( "value" )] );
});
```

I would love to fire a method call in the 'slide' event. How could I accomplish that. I know I could to it with PageMethods - but the method which I would like to call is not static.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using MVC its very easy to use `$.get` to call a controller action.

If you're using web forms, I've posted a solution in the past that you can read here:

[calling a public function of an asp.net ajax server control from client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357085/calling-a-public-function-of-an-asp-net-ajax-server-control-from-client-side/6357188)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I always think Mobile Construction Vehicle from Command & Conquer games and say MCV instead of MVC. Every. Single. Time. :)